# axios post request to local host

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, fetch-api

I have some problems using axios to request posts from react, the code looks like this:

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost/priangan/api/user/login", {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    },
    data: {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 200) alert("Login Success");
  });
```

but when I request, there is some error in console like this, localhost is not found:

[image: error in console]

then I try using fetch, the code is like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost/priangan/api/user/login", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 200) alert("Login Success");
  });
```

Its work,
so what is my problem in using axios?
thanks for helping me

Comment: In the image you described, there is`http//localhost...`. So the extra `/` might be causing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use correct syntax. Let's try this.

```
axios.post(
  "http://localhost/priangan/api/user/login",
  {
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
  },
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    }
  }
)
```

So basically, `axios.post` accepts 3 params in the order: URL, data and options. Your provided `data` and `headers` key are invalid.

Official document: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases